# Structure coefficients for inhomogeneous scaling of the metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a $(n+1)$-dimensional Riemannian manifold.
Let $\{\alpha^0,\ldots,\alpha^n\}$ be a local orthonormal coframe, so that the metric $g$ locally reads $g = \sum_{j=0}^n \alpha^j\otimes \alpha^j$.
The structure equations in this coframe are
\begin{align}
d\alpha^j &= - \omega^j_k\wedge \alpha^k, & \forall j &\in \{0,\ldots,n\}   \\
0 &= \omega^i_j + \omega^j_i, & \forall i,j&\in \{0,\ldots,n\}.
\end{align}
I am trying to derive the structure coefficients of an inhomogeneous scaling of the metric.
More precisely, for $A$ and $B$ two positive constants, consider $\bar{\alpha}^0 = A \alpha^0$ and $\bar{\alpha}^j = B \alpha^j$ for $j\in \{1,\ldots,n\}$.
Let $\bar{g} = \sum_{j=0}^n \bar{\alpha}^j\otimes\bar{\alpha}^j$.
What are the structure coefficients $\bar{\omega}^i_j$ of $\bar{g}$ in the orthonormal coframe $\{\bar{\alpha}^0,\ldots,\bar{\alpha}^n\}$?

A quick inspection shows that
\begin{align}
d\bar{\alpha}^0 &= -\omega^0_0\wedge \bar{\alpha}^0 - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{A}{B} \omega^0_k\wedge\bar{\alpha}^k, \\
d\bar{\alpha}^j &= -\frac{B}{A}\omega^j_0\wedge \bar{\alpha}^0 - \sum_{k=1}^n \omega^j_k\wedge \bar{\alpha}^k, & \forall j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}.
\end{align}
It is tempting to conclude that $\bar{\omega}^0_j = \frac{A}{B} \omega^0_j$ and $\bar{\omega}^j_0 = \frac{B}{A}\omega^j_0$ for $j\in \{1,\ldots,n\}$.
But this cannot be true: this won't make the coefficients $\bar{\omega}^i_j$  skew symmetric as soon as $A \neq B$.

My guess is that $\bar{\omega}^0_j = \frac{A}{B}\omega^0_j + f^0_j \bar{\alpha}^0$ and $\bar{\omega}^j_0 = \frac{B}{A}\omega^j_0 + f^j_0\bar{\alpha}^j$, with $\{f^i_j\}$ some functions (presumably constant functions).
I couldn't manage to go further than that yet.

Of course, my goal is to derive the curvature of $\bar{g}$ in terms of the curvature of $g$.

Comment: You can find the coefficients of the new connection one form directly by the Koszul equation.  First find what the new orthonormal frame is with respect to the old orthonormal frame, then using this new orthonormal frame, you should be able to find how $\bar{\omega}^i_j$ scales.

Comment: @Chris Obviously, if $\{e_0,\ldots,e_n\}$ is the $g$-orthonormal dual frame of $\{\alpha^0,\ldots,\alpha^n\}$, then $\{A^{-1}e_0,B^{-1}e_1,\ldots,B^{-1}e_n\}$ is the $\bar{g}$-orthonormal dual frame of $\{\bar{\alpha}^0,\ldots,\bar{\alpha}^n\}$. I don't understand what you mean: the coefficients $\bar{\omega}^i_j$ won't just be scaling of $\omega^i_j$, for the reason I mentioned above: we won't obtain a skew symmetric matrix.

Comment: I misspoke, it won't just be a scaling, but the method still works.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g$ be your original metric, and $\{e_i\}$ an orthonormal frame. Then define the coefficients by:
\begin{align*}
[e_a,e_b]=\Omega_{ab}^ce_c
\end{align*}
Furthermore, in this local frame write the Levi-Civita connection as:
\begin{align*}
\nabla e_a=\omega_a^b\otimes e_b
\end{align*}
for one forms $\omega_a^b$. The metric compatibility of $\nabla$ forces these one forms to be skew symmetric in the indices $a$ and $b$. We note that:
\begin{align*}
g(e_a,e_b)=\delta_{ab}
\end{align*}
implying that the first three terms in the Koszul equation vanish. Furthermore, we have that:
\begin{align*}
g([e_c,e_a],e_b)=g(\Omega_{ca}^de_d,e_b)=\Omega_{ca}^d\delta_{db}=\Omega^b_{ca}
\end{align*}
Furthermore:
\begin{align*}
g(\nabla_{e_c}e_a,e_b)=g(\omega_a^d(e_c)e_d,e_b)=\omega_a^d(e_c)\delta_{db}=\omega_a^b(e_c)
\end{align*}
The Koszul equations then implies that:
\begin{align*}
\omega_a^b(e_c)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\Omega_{ca}^b-\Omega_{ab}^c+\Omega_{bc}^a\right)
\end{align*}
It follows that if $\{\bar{e}_0,\dots ,\bar{e}_{n+1}\}=\{A_0^{-1}e_0,\dots, A_{n+1}^{-1}e_n\}$, then
the new connection one form is defined by:
\begin{align*}
\bar{\omega}^b_a(\bar{e}_c)=\frac{1}{2}\left(
\bar{\Omega}_{ca}^b-\bar{\Omega}_{ab}^c+\bar{\Omega}_{bc}^a\right)
\end{align*}
where:
\begin{align*}
[\bar{e}_a,\bar{e}_b]=\bar{\Omega}^c_{ab}\bar{e}_c
\end{align*}
Note that:
\begin{align*}
[\bar{e}_a,\bar{e}_b]=A_a^{-1}A_b^{-1}[e_a,e_b]=A_a^{-1}A_b^{-1}\Omega_{ab}^ce_c
\end{align*}
so:
\begin{align*}
A_a^{-1}A_b^{-1}\Omega_{ab}^ce_c=A_c^{-1}\bar{\Omega}^c_{ab}e_c
\end{align*}
implying that:
\begin{align*}
\bar{\Omega}^c_{ab}=A_cA_a^{-1}A_b^{-1}\Omega_{ab}^c
\end{align*}
hence:
\begin{align*}
\bar{\omega}_a^b(\bar{e}_c)=\frac{1}{2}\left(A_c^{-1}A_a^{-1}A_b\Omega_{ca}^b -A_a^{-1}A_b^{-1}A_c\Omega_{ab}^c +A_b^{-1}A_c^{-1}A_a\Omega_{bc}^a\right)
\end{align*}
This is about the best I can do, but maybe some ugly algebra can help you rewrite this in terms of $\omega_a^b$.

Comment: Thanks a lot (+1), this is valuable, although this is not exactly what I'm looking for (if any such thing exists). I was hoping that there was some more explicit form of the $\bar{\omega}$ in terms of the $\omega$.

Comment: @Didier Yea I thought maybe this process would get me to some expression in terms of $\omega$, but I think it’s hard because it’s not just the indices of the matrix one form that get changed, it’s also the internal components (I.e. the one form part of the tensor product) which change under this transformation. I hesitate to say something’s impossible, but based off what I’ve done it does seem it errs on that side of the spectrum.

Comment: I managed to derive a nice expression of the connection $1$-form thanks to your observation on Koszul's formula. Basically, your 7th equation reads $2\omega^i_j(e_k) = \alpha^i([e_k,e_j]) + \alpha^j([e_i,e_k]) -\alpha^k([e_j,e_i])$. Noticing that $\alpha^k([e_j,e_i]) = -d\alpha^k(e_j,e_i)$, one obtains, for instance, $\bar{\omega}^0_j(\bar{e}_k) = B/A \omega^0_j(e_k) \pm (B/A - A/B) d\alpha^0(e_j,e_k)$ (or something like this). If I have time, I will post an answer expliciting this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Didier Oh I see, very clever. I'll try and work out the details myself as well.